# How to Sort Date fields in Material React Table (MRT)?

Tags: reactjs, material-react-table

I use Material React Table (MRT) in my React app. I have a date field and the date is in this format "`31-08-2023 09:52:55`". **The problem is the field is not sorting correctly. It only takes front-side characters to sort, so as it seems, it is sorting by considering it as just a string, but not a date. But it should consider the month and the year and the time too**

This is my Code.

```
export const DATE_FORMATS = {
  D_M_Y_TIME: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss',
  Y_M_D_TIME: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
};

export const getLocalDateTime = (value: any, format?: any) => {
  const localDate = value
    ? moment
        .utc(value, format || DATE_FORMATS.D_M_Y_TIME)
        .local()
        .format(DATE_FORMATS.D_M_Y_TIME)
    : value;
  return localDate;
};

  const processLastModifiedDate = (row: any) => {
    return (
      <Tooltip
        placement="top-start"
        title={getLocalDateTime(row.original.lastModifiedDate)}
      >
        <span
          style={{
            width: 'calc(100% - 15px)',
            overflow: 'hidden',
            textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
          }}
        >
          {getLocalDateTime(row.original.lastModifiedDate)}
        </span>
      </Tooltip>
    );
  };

 const columns = useMemo<MRT_ColumnDef<User>[]>(
    () => [
      {
        accessorKey: 'lastModifiedDate',
        header: 'Last Updated',
        Cell: ({ row }) => processLastModifiedDate(row),
        sortingFn: 'datetime',
      },
    ],
    [],
  );
```

I tried the following method to use as a custom sorting function. It showed a different result, but still wrong sorting.

```
sortingFn: (rowA: any, rowB: any) => {
  const dateA = new Date(getLocalDateTime(rowA.original.lastModifiedDate));
  const dateB = new Date(getLocalDateTime(rowB.original.lastModifiedDate));

  return dateA.getTime() - dateB.getTime();
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First, define the columns for your Material-UI React Table, including the date column(s) you want to sort, and then customize the sorting logic. Finally apply the custom sorting function to the relevant date column(s) in the sortComparator property of the column definition

import React from 'react';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';

```
const YourComponent = () => {
  // Sample data with a date field
  const data = [
    { id: 1, name: 'John Doe', dateOfBirth: '1990-01-15' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Jane Smith', dateOfBirth: '1985-03-20' },
    // ... more data
  ];

  const columns = [
    { title: 'ID', field: 'id' },
    { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
    {
      title: 'Date of Birth',
      field: 'dateOfBirth',
      // Custom sort function for the date column
      sortComparator: (a, b) => {
        const dateA = new Date(a.dateOfBirth);
        const dateB = new Date(b.dateOfBirth);
        return dateA - dateB;
      },
    },
  ];

  return (
    <MaterialTable
      title="Table Title"
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
    />
  );
};
```

export default YourComponent;

Comment: it is not working